# Dove si mette 'per favore', all'inizio o alla fine della frase?

Tags: grammar, phrases

Dove si mette 'per favore', all'inizio o alla fine della frase?
Per esempio:
1. Due biglietti d'autobus per Roma, per favore.
2.Per favore, due biglietti d'autobus per Roma.

Comment: Direi che è abbastanza indifferente, risulta corretto in entrambi i modi.

Comment: In molti contesti può trovarsi anche in mezzo alla frase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilizzare ***per favore*** all'inizio o alla fine di una frase è abbastanza indifferente, nel complesso la frase risulta corretta in entrambi i modi.

C'è da dire che ponendolo all'inizio della frase, specie quando si parla con sconosciuti, dà alla stessa una connotazione di estrema cortesia verso l'interlocutore a cui, ad esempio, si sta chiedendo un'informazione.